# Not a duplicate? What does it mean for 'sense' to be 'an intrinsic property of the word', and to give the word 'its power of referring to something'?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Can [What does it mean for 'sense' to be 'an intrinsic property of the word', and to give the word 'its power of referring to something'?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/28883/5306) please be reopened? I improved the title to stress that it doesn't duplicate [What does 'sense' mean in layman's terms?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/7080/what-does-sense-mean-in-laymans-terms?noredirect=1&lq=1). [Prof. Lawler](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/28883/in-laymans-terms-what-does-sense-mean#comment60315_28883)'s comment can help.

Answer (score 5):

Can you explain how this is a question about linguistics? It is a question about linguistics to ask "what does 'sense' mean, *qua* technical term of linguistics", but you now know what "sense" means. What does it *mean* to ask, as a question of linguistics, "What does it mean for 'sense' to be 'an intrinsic property of the word', and to give the word 'its power of referring to something'?". Are you really asking a question about meaning, or are you asking someone to justify Roberts' choice of words? Even though the terms you're using are terms used in linguistics, I don't understand what intrinsically linguistic question you are asking.

Comment: I'm asking what he means by 'an intrinsic property of the word', and to give the word 'its power of referring to something'.

Comment: I don't see how anyone would know that that is what you are asking, given your question.

Comment: Well, if _Sinn und Bedeutung_ is not a linguistic consideration, then semantics might as well move over to a different department. In a linguistics book, one expects to read linguistics; if one doesn't understand it, one asks linguists what it means. We see this all the time here; I admit this is a complex subject, but wishing it away won't solve anything.